# Is it possible pass a function as a parameter in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do you pass a function as a parameter in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c)

Is it possible pass a function as a parameter in C? If yes, how?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't pass a 'function' as a parameter.  You can, however, pass a pointer to a function instead.

When you reference a function by name without the parentheses for a function invocation, you are referencing a pointer to a function.  Thus, for example, we could consider a function that generates a table of values for a mathematical function:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void generator(double lo, double hi, double inc, double (*function)(double))
{
    double x;
    for (x = lo; x < hi; x += inc)
        printf("x = %6g; f(x) = %6g\n", x, (*function)(x))
}

int main(void)
{
     generator(0.0, 1.0, 0.02, sin);
     generator(0.0, 1.0, 0.02, cos);
     generator(0.0, 1.0, 0.02, sqrt);
     return(0);
}
```

Here, the functions 'sin()', 'cos()', and 'sqrt()' all have the same prototype schema: function taking a double argument and returning a double value.  Note that if I mistakenly wrote:

```
generator(0.0, 1.0, 0.02, sin());
```

I would get a bunch of compilation errors - one because 'sin()' expects an argument, and another because 'generator()' expects a pointer to a function and not a double value as the last argument.

(Also note that a good program would at least identify the function it is calculating, and the repeated increments of a double number is not a good idea for accuracy.  It is but an example.)

Answer (score 9):

Use a pointer to function.
Like `int (*ptr2_fun)()`
Receiving function being:
 `int execute_your_function(int (*fun)())`

Here you have some [examples](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

Comment: check qsort(). It accepts a comparison function.

Answer (score 6):

Use [function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**. Not a function *per se* but a pointer to a function instead.

See [`qsort()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/qsort.html).

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) { /* ... */ }
/* ... */
qsort(data, nelems, sizeof *data, cmp); /* pass the function `cmp` to qsort() */
```

Answer (score 3):

Great function pointer tutorial here:

http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use a function pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void (*bar_callback)(void);

void foo(void)
{
  puts("foo");
}

void bar(bar_callback callback)
{
  puts("bar");
  callback();
}
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  bar(foo);
  return 0;
}
```