# C - What is the type definition of a variable in the following code?

Tags: c, typedef, type-definition

What is the type definition of a variable `x` in this code?

```
typedef int *f(int);
f *x;
```

Comment: Is it for a computer science classe assignment?

Comment: @Diti , No, it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

`f` is an alias for a function type that takes `int` as an argument and returns an `int*`.

As such it isn't particularly useful.

(If you wanted `f` to be a *pointer* to a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`,  you'd have to write `typedef int (*f)(int);`)

Comment: Style nit-pick: the OP's style is actually quite useful for people who prefer a consistent style when they work with any kind of pointers. If you use the typedef from the OP, you can declare a function pointer variable as `f* ptr;`. Rather than hiding the pointer behind typedef as in your case, and ending up with the more mysterious declaration `f ptr;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef int* f(int);
```

type `f` is function with `int` parameters and returning pointer to `int`.

You cannot define a function using a `typedef` for a function type. please see the [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574985/typedef-a-functions-prototype) answer.