# Using the type of the function in std::function to declare multiple functions of that type

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have

```
typedef std::function<
    double(
        int,
        long
    )
> FooType;
```

and I want to declare function prototypes for a series of functions that I can slot into a `std::function` of this type. I know I can write

```
double foo1(int, long);
double foo2(int, long);
```

etc., but is there a way I can use `FooType` somehow when declaring the function prototypes? Something like

`FooType::type foo1, foo2;`

Perhaps I might have to use `(*foo1)` or similar? Naturally in the implementation of the function I'd need to spell it out long hand so I can put in some parameters, but writing it as above would keep my header file cleaner.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure you can, just as always*, using partial specialization:

```
template <typename> struct fn_sig;
template <typename T> struct fn_sig<std::function<T>> { using type = T; };
```

Usage:

```
fn_sig<FooType>::type f;

double f(int a, long b) { return double(a) /  b; }
```

(You'll obviously need to spell the underlying function type out for the function definition.)

---

<sub>*) Meaning that this is the same answer for any question of the form "can I get the template parameter from a template specializaton".</sub>

Comment: And as usual for something like this, it can be simplified with an alias template: `template<typename T> using fn_sig_t = typename fn_sig<T>::type;`

Comment: @BЈовић See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4575007/1774667 -- this is a C ism

Comment: @Yakk So, that means that a function declaration and a function pointer variable are same thing, right?

Comment: @bj no?  One has a `*`?

Answer (score 9):

> writing it as above would keep my header file cleaner

It would be cleaner (with less metaprogramming) to go the other way around: Start with the `foo()` declaration and create `FooType` from it.

```
double foo(int, long);

typedef std::function< decltype(foo) > FooType;
```

Since there are presumably several such functions, two typedefs might be the optimal factoring:

```
typedef double FooFn(int, long);
typedef std::function< FooFn > FooType;

FooFn foo1, foo2, foo3;
```

Of course, in the implementation (.cpp) file the signature needs to be written longhand.

One more thing, note that `std::function` is a heavyweight generalization of function pointers. If you'll only ever assign ordinary functions into it, a function pointer might be better, and this would be a drop-in replacement:

```
typedef FooFn * FooType;
```

Comment: This is a great idea but something that I omitted from the question is that I have many functions `foo` with the same signature. But I will upvote this, with my apologies.

Comment: @MichaelBullock Got ya covered, see the edit I'm about to post.

Comment: `If you'll only ever assign ordinary functions into it, a function pointer might be better` +1, with the addition that captureless lambdas can also be represented by plain funcptrs.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this by creating a template `struct` which destructures the type of `FooType`, matching `T` in `std::function< T >`:

```
template <typename T>
struct destructure;

template <typename T>
struct destructure<std::function<T>>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using destructure_t = typename destructure<T>::type;
```

After that, you can use `destructure_t` to declare your function:

```
destructure_t<FooType> foo;

int main()
{
    foo(1, 20l);
}
```

Then, you can define it with the regular function syntax:

```
double foo(int i, long l)
{
    std::cout << i << " " << l << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Your `main` will print "1 20".

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UQP4h0Du9Fxor18J)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution to the working one presented by [@KerrekSB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613024/4987285), you can use a function declaration and an alias as it follows if you want to get a pointer type:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template<typename F> F * get(std::function<F>);
template<typename F> using FPtr = decltype(get(std::declval<F>()));

double f(int, long) { return {}; }

int main() {
    using FooType = std::function<double(int, long)>;
    FPtr<FooType> myF = f;
    (void)myF;
}
```

Or a slightly modified version if you want only the actual type:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template<typename F> F * get(std::function<F>);
template<typename F> using MyType = typename std::remove_pointer<decltype(get(std::declval<F>()))>::type;

double f(int, long) { return {}; }

int main() {
    using FooType = std::function<double(int, long)>;
    MyType<FooType> *myF = f;
    (void)myF;
}
```