# C++ using function as parameter

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a function called

```
void funct2(int a) {

}


void funct(int a, (void)(*funct2)(int a)) {

 ;


}
```

what is the proper way to call this function? What do I need to setup to get it to work?

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c

Comment: You have two functions, which one are you having problems calling? Note that you have hidden the function `funct2` in `funct` by having an identically named pointer-to-function parameter so you will have to fully qualify `funct2` to call it directly from inside `funct`.

Comment: Right on, because C++ is C as we all know. Welcome to CloseOverflow. In case one uses C++11 there is good read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111285/how-to-pass-and-execute-anonymous-function-as-parameter-in-c11 -- avoiding passing functions with pointers improves readability.

Comment: A more complete set of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111285/how-to-pass-and-execute-anonymous-function-as-parameter-in-c11

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the referenced question about C? It is possible that C++ provides (or at some point will provide) a different approach.

Comment: @pooya13 It's not a duplicate. There are other ways to pass functions as parameters in C++ that are not possible in C (using [functors](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Function-Objects-Functors-in-C-Part-1), for example).

Comment: [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Normally, for readability's sake, you use a typedef to define the custom type like so:

```
typedef void (* vFunctionCall)(int args);
```

when defining this typedef you want the returning argument type for the function prototypes you'll be pointing to, to *lead* the typedef identifier (in this case the void type) and the prototype arguments to *follow* it (in this case "int args").

When using this typedef as an argument for another function, you would define your function like so (this typedef can be used almost exactly like any other object type):

```
void funct(int a, vFunctionCall funct2) { ... }
```

and then used like a normal function, like so:

```
funct2(a);
```

So an entire code example would look like this:

```
typedef void (* vFunctionCall)(int args);

void funct(int a, vFunctionCall funct2)
{
   funct2(a);
}

void otherFunct(int a)
{
   printf("%i", a);
}

int main()
{
   funct(2, (vFunctionCall)otherFunct);
   return 0;
}
```

and would print out:

```
2
```

Comment: Since C++11, one would rather use `using vFunctionCall = void (*)(int args);` for better readability. Or even better, use [std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848690/should-i-use-stdfunction-or-a-function-pointer-in-c)

Comment: There is no need to do any casting.

Comment: Since C++11 I would rather like to see std::function<>

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `std::function<void(int)>` does *much more* than `void (*)(int args)`, and is therefor harder for the platform to optimise

Answer (score 38):

Another way to do it is using the functional library.

`std::function<output (input)>`

Here reads an example, where we would use `funct2` inside `funct`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void displayMessage(int a) {
    std::cout << "Hello, your number is: " << a << '\n';
}

void printNumber(int a, std::function<void (int)> func) {
    func(a);
}

int main() {
    printNumber(3, displayMessage);
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
Hello, your number is: 3
```

Comment: Can I use this syntax to pass a public method of class A to the constructor of class B and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

The basic C++ way is using [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which acts like a "function type", for example the type `int -> double` in a functional language. It's not actually a type but a class template for which class instances can hold a callable function, but it's useful to think of it as used in places you would use a function type.

For example, this function takes `int` and returns `double`:

```
double halve(int x)
{
    return x / 2;
}
```

Now you can assign functions themselves (functions as first-class citizens):

```
std::function<double(int)> f = halve; // can store a lambda too
```

and you can pass it in as an argument type, or a return type. Ex:

```
double call_f(std::function<double(int)> f, int x)
{
    return f(x);
}
```

Another option is to use templates. The compiler will figure out the types and generate correctly typed code. See [this comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25848890/3163618).

Answer (score -1):

A more elaborate and general (not abstract) example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
int Mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
int Power(int a, int b)
{
    while (b > 1)
    {
        a = a * a;
        b -= 1;
    }
    return a;
}
int Calculator(std::function<int(int, int)> foo, int a, int b)
{
    return foo(a, b);
}
int main()
{
    cout << std::endl
         << "Sum: " << Calculator(Add, 1, 2);
    cout << std::endl
         << "Mul: " << Calculator(Mul, 1, 2);
    cout << std::endl
         << "Power: " << Calculator(Power, 5, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel like this doesn't add enough value compared to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982640/11107541) to warrant being a separate answer.

Answer (score -3):

check this

```
typedef void (*funct2)(int a);

void f(int a)
{
    print("some ...\n");
}

void dummy(int a, funct2 a)
{
     a(1);
}

void someOtherMehtod
{
    callback a = f;
    dummy(a)
}
```

Comment: That's C, not C++