# Function as a member "variable" in class

Tags: c++, calculator

I was thinking about how to improve my simple calculator using some advanced techniques. I came to question, is there some way to create a class with function you could define per instance:

```
class Function
{
public:
    Function(function);
    ~Function();

private:
    function;
};
```

So for example you create an instance

```
Function divide(int x / int y); //For example
```

I hope you understand the question.

EDIT:

So I studied the `void (*foo)(int)` method. It could be used. But the initial idea was to create a generic function that holds the function itself in it. Not just a pointer to a function defined outside. So you could do something like this:

```
int main() {

//Define the functions
Function divide( X / Y ); //Divide
Function sum( X + Y ); //Sum

//Ask the user what function to call and ask him to enter variables x and y

//User chooses divide and enters x, y 
cout << divide.calculate(x, y) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer:
@Chris Drew pointed out:
*Sure, your `Function` can store a `std::function<int(int, int)>` and then you can construct `Function` with a lambda: e.g: `Function divide([](int x,int y){return x / y;});` But then I'm not sure what your `Function` offers that you can't just do with `std::function`.*

It answers my question, unfortunately my question was put on hold so I cannot mark the question resolved.

Comment: You mean something like a function pointer: `int (*function)(int,int))`?

Comment: What's your intention? Could you provide more examples?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes something like this

Comment: `std::function<int(int, int)>` may help also for binery function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use std::function or a function pointer in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848690/should-i-use-stdfunction-or-a-function-pointer-in-c)

Comment: Sure, your `Function` can store a `std::function<int(int, int)>` and then you can construct `Function` with a lambda: e.g: `Function divide([](int x,int y){return x / y;});` But then I'm not sure what your `Function` offers that you can't just do with `std::function`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Well that explains how to do it. Thanks! Could you write an answer so I can mark it as resolved?

Comment: @BBPP20Development I'd love to but your question is "on hold" because it was deemed to be unclear what you were asking. Perhaps now that you have added an edit explaining your intentions it will be reopened.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I already edited it several times. Shame. I will mention the answer in my next edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, your `Function` can store a [`std::function<int(int, int)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and then you can construct `Function` with a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Function {
  std::function<int(int, int)> function;
public:
  Function(std::function<int(int, int)> f) : function(std::move(f)){};
  int calculate(int x, int y){ return function(x, y); }
};

int main() {
  Function divide([](int x, int y){ return x / y; });
  std::cout << divide.calculate(4, 2) << "\n";  
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8f2DACAWhXMXI57F).

But then, as it stands, I'm not sure what `Function` offers that you can't do with a `std::function` directly:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using Function = std::function<int(int, int)>;

int main() {
  Function divide([](int x, int y){ return x / y; });
  std::cout << divide(4, 2) << "\n";  
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/diF5t8I0U1Jnu1QF).

Comment: Using function<> as member has the advantage of polymorphic behavior by switching the function of the same interface but with different implementation (could be at construction time, or at runtime).  For example draw() from a shape object.  the shape could be triangle or circle.  This happens in my design in certain projects (you don't want to start a new derived class, just want to use a different method)