# Template function as argument in a class

Tags: c++, function, class, arguments

I wanna pass a function argument in the constructor of the following class:

```
template <class T>
class Class
{
private:
    bool (*fc)(T, T);
public:
    template <class T>
    Class(const bool(*func)(T, T))
    {

    }
    ~Class() {}
};

bool randomFunction(int a, int b)
{
    return a <= b;
}


int main() {
    LDI<int> test(randomFunction);
    return 0;
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'Class::Class(const bool (__cdecl *)(T,T))': cannot convert argument 1 from 'bool (__cdecl *)(int,int)' to 'const bool (__cdecl *)(T,T)

Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "Class::Class[with T=int]" matches the argument list

How do I fix it and where's the problem?

Comment: Why not take a `std::function `?

Comment: The issue is you have two different function signatures. One is const bool, the other is bool

Comment: You need to show code that's a minimal version of the code you expect to compile, which means all other errors must be fixed first. For example, your code currently has a mismatch between the names `Class` and `LDI`, and reuses the template parameter name `T` in a nested scope.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the template part before the constructor, and use a `std::function` to simplify your code.

```cpp
#include <functional>

template <class T> class LDI
{
public:
    // Define this type using std::function, so it can accept function, lambdas, ... very easily.
    // If used with std::bind, can also accept pointers to members functions.
    typedef std::function<bool(T,T)> tmplfunc ;
private:
    tmplfunc fc ;
public:
    // No template here, class is already a template.
    LDI(tmplfunc aFc)
    {
        fc = aFc ;
    }
    ~LDI() {}
};

bool randomFunction(int a, int b)
{
    return a <= b;
}

int main() {
    LDI<int> test(randomFunction);
    LDI<double> test2([](double a, double b) -> bool { return a<=b ;});
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using `#include <functional>`, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964526/function-as-a-member-variable-in-class) of defining a class that has a function as a variable-style member provided through the constructor.
Although I wouldn't recommend the current implementation, geeksforgeeks has a good resource on [functions as arguments](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-cpp/) that can be applied to your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem. First is just removing the `const` from the return type of the parameter `func` and second is using `std::function`.

##### Method 1

Here we remove the `const` from the return type of the parameter `func` in the constructor. Also, there is no need for the constructor to be separately templated.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class LDI
{
private:
    bool (*fc)(T, T);
public:
    LDI(bool(*func)(T, T)): fc(func)
    {
       std::cout<<"constructor called"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~LDI() {}
};

bool randomFunction(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout<<"randomFunction called"<<std::endl;
    return a <= b;
}


int main() {
    LDI<int> test(randomFunction);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/jaOOmBojb)

##### Method 2

Here we use `std::function`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
template <typename T>
class LDI
{
private:
    std::function<bool (T, T)> fc; //use std::function
public:
    LDI(std::function<bool (T, T)> func): fc(func)//use std::function in the parameter
    {
       std::cout<<"constructor called"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~LDI() {}
};

bool randomFunction(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout<<"randomFunction called"<<std::endl;
    return a <= b;
}


int main() {
    LDI<int> test(randomFunction);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/GD4LxkYXi)