# Can you pass a function so you can later call it?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

I want to have objects with one method which calls a function (but every object should have a different function to call). I will try to show you what I mean by showing an example:

```
class Human
{
    public:
        void setMyFunction(void func);  // specify which function to call
        void callMyFunction();  // Call the specified function
};

void Human::setMyFunction(void func)    // ''
{
    myFunction = func;
}

void Human::callMyFunction()    // ''
{
    myFunction();
}

void someRandomFunction()   // A random function
{
    // Some random code
}

int main()
{
    Human Lisa;     // Create Object
    Lisa.setMyFunction();   // Set the function for that object
    Lisa.callMyFunction();  // Call the function specified earlier
}
```

This code (obviously) doesn't work but I hope you understand what I am trying to accomplish.

MfG, TPRammus

Comment: You will want to use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: Is the signature for the function you want to pass to the class going to be the same or should it accept `int(int, int)`, `double(double)` and `void(int)` ...?

Comment: You could also use a [function pointer](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, looks like simple function pointer will do, which would be more efficient, `than std::function`.

Comment: @SergeyA perhaps, but `std::function` is an important tool to know about when dealing with this kind of problem, even if it's not the right one for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use `std::function`.

```
#include <functional>

class Human
{
    std::function<void()> mFunc;
public:
    void setMyFunction(std::function<void()> func) { mFunc = func; }
    void callMyFunction() { if (mFunc) mFunc(); }
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/V7YLaI)

Comment: Why `std::function`?

Comment: To be generic and to allow capturing lambda.

Comment: But does OP needs it? There is a cost associated with it. Thanks for edit, btw

Comment: Thank you very much this solution works. I tried this before but it didn't work because noone told me to `#include <functional>` (which I figured out right now).

Comment: @SergeyA: I think it would be premature optimization. but pointer is also possible indeed.

Comment: @SergeyA I refer you to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25848890/7359094)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I know the benefits of `std::function`. I am also aware of it's penalties. For example, it calls for terrible syntax with overloaded functions.

Comment: @Jarod42 Now the function doesn't get called and if I remove `if (mFunc)` I get an error `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'`

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you for your effort! But in [my implementation](http://ideone.com/qaSsRq) it seems to not work properly (I have two classes).

**Edit:** Nevermind. I needed to return the address of the object instead of the object himself **(** `Human & getHuman() { return lisa; }` **)**. [Code Example](http://ideone.com/UFB4KJ)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a simple function pointer. Just do this:

```
class Human
{
    public:
        using func_t = void (*)(); 
        void setMyFunction(func_t f) {
             func = f;
        }
        void callMyFunction() {
             func();
        }
     private:
        func_t func;
};
```

The reasons why one might prefer function pointers to `std::function` are:

- Performance. Calling `std::function` tends to be slower, than calling a function by pointer.
- `std::function` needs truly ugly syntax when one needs to bind it to an overloaded function.

Example:

```
void foo();
void foo(int x = 0);

void check() {
  Human h;
  h.setMyFunction(&foo);
}
```

Will fail to compile.

Comment: Downvoting is cool. Explaining the reason for it is even cooler.