# How to understand the typedef in this declaration

Tags: c++, typedef, forward-declaration, effective-c++

Recently, I read the book *Effective C++* and there is a declaration about typedef in Item 35 which confuses me.

```
class GameCharacter; // Question1: Why use forward declaration?

int defaultHealthCalc(const GameCharacter& gc);

class GameCharacter{

    public:
        typedef int (*HealthCalcFunc)(const GameCharacter&); // Question 2: What does this mean?

        explicit GameCharacter(HealthCalcFunc hcf = defaultHealthCalc)
            : healthFunc(hcf)
        {}

        int healthValue() const
        {return healthFunc(*this); }

    private:
        HealthCalcFunc healthFunc;
};
```

So my first question is: Why does the author use a forward declaration here? Is there any specific reason?

And my second question is: How do I understand the typedef declaration, and how do I use it? I just know something like `typedef int MyInt;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So my first question is that why the author use forward declaration here?

So that the compiler knows that `GameCharacter` is a valid name when the `int defaultHealthCalc(const GameCharacter& gc);` line is encountered.

> And my second question is how to understand the typedef declaration and how to use it?

Ideally, you do *not* use it anymore.

Starting with C++11, `using` is a superior alternative because it's more readable; unlike `typedef`'ed function pointers, it clearly separates the name from that which the name describes. Compare this:

> ```
> typedef int (*HealthCalcFunc)(const GameCharacter&);
> ```

With this:

```
using HealthCalcFunc = int (*)(const GameCharacter&);
```

In the `typedef` version, the name `HealthCalcFunc` is surrounded on both sides by that which the name describes. This hurts readability.

---

But the code can still be improved, because C++11 also introduced `std::function` as an alternative to and/or an abstraction layer above function pointers.

```
using HealthCalcFunc = std::function<int(const GameCharacter&)>;
```

This is so readable it hardly has to be explained at all. `HealthCalcFunc` is a function which returns an `int` and takes a `const GameCharacter&`.

The `defaultHealthCalc` function fits into this definition. Here's a full example:

```
#include <functional>

class GameCharacter;

int defaultHealthCalc(const GameCharacter& gc);

class GameCharacter {
public:
      using HealthCalcFunc = std::function<int(const GameCharacter&)>; 

      explicit GameCharacter(HealthCalcFunc hcf = defaultHealthCalc)
       : healthFunc(hcf)
      {}
      int healthValue() const
      {return healthFunc(*this); }
private:
       HealthCalcFunc healthFunc;
};
```

The great thing about `std::function` is that you are not restricted to free-standing functions. You can pass every function-like thing. Here are some examples:

```
struct Functor
{
    int f(const GameCharacter& gc);
};

int main()
{
    // normal function:
    GameCharacter character1(defaultHealthCalc);

    // lambda:
    GameCharacter character2([](auto const& gc) { return 123; });

    // using std::bind:
    Functor functor;
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    GameCharacter character3(std::bind(&Functor::f, functor, _1));
}
```

See also [Should I use std::function or a function pointer in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848690/should-i-use-stdfunction-or-a-function-pointer-in-c).

Comment: _"Because the code can still be **improved**"_: mentioning `std::function` here is appropriate, but it is a fully different alternative, and for a simple example such as this one, it might be mis-leading to mention improvements when switching from a light weight function pointer type to the entirely different and, in comparison, "heavy" creature of `std::function`. Both have their place (mostly, imo, `std::function` should be preferred, but when working with older APIs ...), but are very different concepts, and whether to use one over the other should be weighted against the context.

Comment: @dfri: I think `std::function` is much simpler to write, read and apply than a  function pointer, so I consider it the standard solution, whereas function pointers are special-purpose beasts.

Comment: Yes I agree, note my ninja-edit. Still, when mentioning `std::function` as an always-improvement, it might be valuable to point out that there are situations where a simple function pointer is to prefer (or even the only alternative). Anyway, good answer, just a minor byline by me above!

Comment: @dfri: I've added a link to a question which examines the advantages and disadvantages of function pointers compared to `std::function`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl This one is the best! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 14):

> So my first question is that why the author use forward declaration here?

Because the declaration of the function `defaultHealthCalc` uses `const GameCharacter&` as the type of the parameter, then `GameCharacter` needs to be declared in advance.

> And my second question is how to understand the typedef declaration

It declares a type name `HealthCalcFunc`, which is a type of pointer to function, which takes `const GameCharacter&` as parameter and returns `int`.

> and how to use it?

Just as the code sample showed,

```
explicit GameCharacter(HealthCalcFunc hcf = defaultHealthCalc) // declare a parameter with type HealthCalcFunc; 
                                                               // the default argument is function pointer to defaultHealthCalc
: healthFunc(hcf)                                              // initialize healthFunc with hcf
{}

int healthValue() const
{return healthFunc(*this); }                                   // invoke the function pointed by healthFunc

HealthCalcFunc healthFunc;                                     // declare a member with type HealthCalcFunc
```

Answer (score 11):

The forward declaration is needed because of the forward declaration of `defaultHealthCalc`, which uses `GameCharacter`. Without forward declaration, the compiler would not know that later, there will be a type named `GameCharacter`, and so you need to forward declare it, or move the definition before the function declaration.

That `typedef` means to name the type `int(*)(const GameCharacter&)` `HealthCalcFunc`. That's a function pointer to a `int(const GameCharacter&)`. For that reason, typedefs are pretty unreadable, it is advised to use a `using` declaration instead:

```
using HealthCalcFunc = int(*)(const GameCharacter&);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
typedef int (*HealthCalcFunc)(const GameCharacter&);
```

Declares a `typedef` named `HealthCalcFunc` for a function pointer type, where the function signature returns a `int` and takes a parameter of `const GameCharacter&`.

The forward declaration is needed because that class is used as parameter type in the `typedef`.

Answer (score 2):

The forward declaration of `GameCharacter` is not strictly needed; the function declaration could have read:

```
int defaultHealthCalc(const class GameCharacter& gc);
```

which has the same effect as the original code. But it is considered more readable to have the forward declaration on its own line.