# How to send a pointer of an overriden virtual function to the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointer-to-member

An example:

```
class Base
{
    protected:
        virtual void function() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
        void callfunction(void (Base::* func)()) { (this->*func)(); }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    public:
        void publicCall() { callfunction(&Derived1::function); }
    private:
        void function() override { std::cout << "Derived1\n"; }
};
```

I would like to be able to send the derived function pointer to the base class to fulfill a pattern that can be specified in the base class. Thus, reusing code.

However, I'm not sure what the type is supposed to be in the base class since Base::* is not a Derived1::*.

I get the following error:
`No instance of overloaded function callfunction matches the argument list: arguments types are (Derived1::*)`

Now obviously, I could change the data type to be `Derived1::*`, but that wouldn't allow me to send in other derived class virtual functions back to `Base` to handle, such as `Derived2::function()`

Can a template sort of function be created like this?

Comment: Your syntax is off: you need `(this->*func)()` and `callFunction(&Derived1::function);`. But yeah, even with that, it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks @Justin I will fix the syntax as an edit. I've had it written that way before, but still doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Must your virtual function be protected? It would work if you used `callfunction(&Base::function)`, but that doesn't work unless the virtual function is public.... Or you could make a protected `auto getfunction() { return &Base::function; }` in `Base`.

Comment: No. I do not want to make it public since these functions are meant to be restricted to the derived classes and not accessible by the client. That's a workaround, but not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the member function pointer to the base class member function pointer type: `callfunction(static_cast<void (Base::*)()>(&Derived1::function));`. Full example:

```cpp
class Base
{
    protected:
        virtual void function() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
        void callfunction(void (Base::* func)()) { (this->*func)(); }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    public:
        void publicCall() { callfunction(static_cast<void (Base::*)()>(&Derived1::function)); }
    private:
        void function() override { std::cout << "Derived1\n"; }
};
```

This is allowed; see [cppreference on pointers to member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions):

> Pointer to member function of a base class can be implicitly converted to pointer to the same member function of a derived class ...
> Conversion in the opposite direction, from a pointer to member function of a derived class to a pointer to member function of an unambiguous non-virtual base class, is allowed with `static_cast` and explicit cast

In this case, we are converting derived to base rather than vice-versa, so we need to `static_cast`.

---

You can avoid requiring the cast from the call-site by casting in `Base` from a template:

```cpp
class Base
{
    protected:
        virtual void function() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
        void callfunction(void (Base::* func)()) { (this->*func)(); }

        template <typename Derived, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<Derived const*, Base const*>, int> = 0>
        void callfunction(void (Derived::* func)()) { callfunction(static_cast<void (Base::*)()>(func)); }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    public:
        void publicCall() { callfunction(&Derived1::function); }
    private:
        void function() override { std::cout << "Derived1\n"; }
};
```

Compiler Explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/3x8qPK4Tf

Comment: I would be willing to do this. However, this template function gets called about 100 times by 10 classes making it very tedious include the cast 1000 times. Therefore, using casting seems quite complicated.

Comment: This is allowed, but if you accidentally try this cast with a non-virtual function, you get UB.

Comment: I appreciate the Compiler Explorer. This is probably the one of the best answers so far. Only trouble I'm having is sometimes I want to send nullptr or NULL as the function pointer because there are cases where I don't want that function to happen in the base class. I want it to skip over it. Is there a solution to that? I'm having issue issues where it can't convert the nullptr to Derived::* @Justin

Comment: @cwbusacker It seems to work for me: https://godbolt.org/z/hY1KhdhMP . Are you just asking how to test a PMF for null? That's the same as other pointers; either `if (func) /* call it */` or `if (func != nullptr) /* call it */`

Comment: @Justin, that works for the base class case. However, in my scenario (tried to simplify my question), I'm actually sending multiple function pointers to the function where some of them may be nullptr and others are not. I don't think nullptr can pass through as a Derived::*. Would the best solution be to maybe make multiple instances of that where a nullptr would be allowed? Or could I somehow change the std::is_convertible_v()?

Comment: @cwbusacker `nullptr` absolutely can be passed through as a `void (Derived::*)()`: https://godbolt.org/z/Ma51cdqnn

Comment: @Justin I got this to work. Thanks for your post. One question: does the ```template <typename Derived, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<Derived const*, Base const*>, int> = 0>``` make it so that the program won't compile if somehow a non-derived class function pointer was sent in?

Comment: @cwbusacker Yes, `std::is_convertible_v<Derived const*, Base const*>` is testing whether `Derived` is publicly derived from `Base` (if you want private/protected derivation, use `std::is_base_of_v<Base, Derived>`. So the `std::enable_if_t` is telling the compiler to enable this overload only if `Derived` is publicly derived from `Base`, i.e., "Only allow this function to be called when `Derived` actually derives from `Base`"

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::function<>` instead of `C` style function pointer.

```
std::function<returnType (parameterType)> functionPointer = functionName;
```

Do not forget to include `<functional>`.

I think this will resolve your problem, but for sure it is preferred.

To pass it directly:

```
void callfunciton(const std::function<void()>& func);
```

and call by

```
callfunction([]{ function(); });
```

EDIT:
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848690/should-i-use-stdfunction-or-a-function-pointer-in-c) to learn why you should use `std::function<>`.

Comment: Just fixed that in the post. I've tried using ```std::function``` but for some reason it doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: I guess the follow up question is, how do I send the function as an argument when using std::function<>? I've tried using &function1 and &Derived1::function1 and without the &.

Comment: Have you included functional?

Comment: Yes, but only in the base class where std::function is used. Do I need to ```#include <functional>``` in the derived classes as well?

Answer (score 2):

Just send `&Base::function`. Since it's virtual, the right one will be called.

The only problem here is that `Base::function` is protected and you cannot access it from `Derived` (strange but true). OTOH `&Derived::function` won't convert to `void (Base::* func)()` (and for a good reason). So you have to either make `Base::function` public, or provide an accessor:

```
class Base { 
  ...
  protected:
    auto getFunction() { return &Base::function; }
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cW3a9K17q)

Comment: Makes sense never thought of that.

Comment: IMO, this is the best solution. It's safe (e.g. my answer is very easy to use incorrectly and cause UB), it's clear. It avoids more complicated language features (e.g. templates). Etc.

Comment: This is my second choice, but I'm dealing with a class of hundreds of functions. Making this solution a lot more difficult to implement.

Comment: @cwbusacker What about pulling out the virtual functions into an interface? E.g. https://godbolt.org/z/13czdbW85 .

Answer (score 1):

I think that a template function should work

```
template<class _DType>
void Base::callFunction(void(_DType::*func)()) { func(); }
```

then the function from `Derived1`

```
void Derived1::publicCall() { Base::callFunction(&Derived1::function); }
```

This work as long as `Derived1` is derived by `Base`, that is not what you wrote but I'm assuming you just missed, anyway next time I would add `class Derived1: public Base` to have a more clear code.

Comment: Doing my civic duty:  Do not name identifiers with leading underscores followed by uppercase letters.  Those names are reserved, and violation of this results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis for what?

Comment: `func();` will not compile. `(this->*func)();` will also not compile.

Comment: `(static_cast<_DType*>(this)->*func)()`

Comment: @CEPB — they’re reserved for use by the implementation. There’s nothing that prohibits the standard library from defining a macro named `_DType`.

Comment: @PeteBecker tnx, is there a list for these, so I can read on them? I just learned that `__something` is reserved for std library.

Comment: The ones you need to avoid are names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter and names that **contain** two consecutive underscores. That second one is an artifact from the days of CFront, which used names with two underscores in the C code that it generated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is asking for CRTP, a poorly named but well known label for the idiom described in a 1995 article by Jim Coplien, titled "A Curiously Recurring Template Pattern".  The idea is well documented, so I won't go into depth, but the idea is pretty simple:  The base class takes a template argument, and the derived class provides its type to the base.  Then the base class can "downcast" the this pointer to the derived type and call the function without needing a virtual call.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

[What is the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp)