# Is it possible to pass a function as a parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

Is there any way to pass a function as a parameter in C++, like [the way that functions can be passed as parameters in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c) I know that it's possible to pass a function as a parameter in C using function pointers, and I want to know whether the same is possible in C++.

Comment: Yes you can. But in C++ we tend to pass functors rather than function pointers as the compiler can optimize them much more efficiently.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Is it vague, ambiguous, or subjective in some way? Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" maybe?

Comment: @MooingDuck But I answered my own question - is posting questions and then answering them considered counter-productive for some reason?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: That has nothing to do with what Mooing just said.

Comment: Answering your own question is totally fine.  But this question is something that is very very easy to test or lookup yourself, either one.

Comment: @MooingDuck I just looked around on Stack Overflow and I noticed that no one had asked or answered this question yet, so I decided to answer it myself.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Lots of easy questions aren't on and do not belong on stackoverflow.  They belong in a google search.

Comment: @AndersonGreen, just FYI: C++ comes very very close to being a superset of C.  This means that generally, anything you can do with with C in C syntax, you can also do in C++ with the same syntax.  The are some exception to that. Function pointers, however, work in C++ pretty much exactly the way they work in C, with the syntax you are familiar with from C.

Comment: @MooingDuck Should I vote to delete this question, then, even though it's gotten a lot of answers that may be helpful or informative to C++ beginners?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but I don't see how this question invites debate, arguments, polling or discussion. Apart from all of these chatty-cathys in the comments of course. Reopening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like in C. But you can also do it the C++ way (C++11, to be exact):

```
// This function takes a function as an argument, which has no
// arguments and returns void.
void foo(std::function<void()> func)
{
    // Call the function.
    func();
}
```

You can pass a normal function to foo()

```
void myFunc();
// ...
foo(myFunc);
```

but you can also pass a lambda expression.  For example:

```
foo([](){ /* code here */ });
```

You can also pass a function object (an object that overloads the `()` operator.) In general, you can pass anything that can be called with the `()` operator.

If you instead use the C way, then the only thing you can pass are normal function pointers.

Comment: I was originally going to write an answer similar to this but you beat me by a couple seconds, so here's the example code I was going to use as an example: [Link](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b101a2f2eaff463715b1553ed551b71f)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible in C++ just as in C to pass functions as parameters but with a few differences: we can use function *references* instead of pointers, templates types in addition to variadic template arguments. For example:

#### Function references:

In C, we don't have the ability to pass objects by reference. This however is possible in C++:

```
void f( void (&)() ) {}

f( h );
```

The difference between references are pointers is subtle, but important. For instance, we can't pass `NULL` or 0 to a function expecting a reference; the argument must be satisfied with its type immediately. References are usually preferred in most cases over pointers.

#### Templates:

Templates allow us to generically pass functions with variable type attributes as parameters:

```
template <class T, class U>
void f( T (&)( U ) ) {}
```

The above signature accepts a function with any return type or parameter list (the only setback is that the function must take one argument).

In addition to this feature, we can also utilize *varaidic* templates to allow functions with variable-length parameter lists:

```
template <class T, class ...U>
void f( T (&)( U... ) ) {}

int h(int, int) { .. }
bool g(std::string) { .. }


f( h );
f( g );
```

The implementation of `f` can also use perfect forwarding if we are using `U&&`:

```
template <class T, class ...U>
void f( T (&fun)( U&&...) ) {

    // ...
    fun( std::forward<U>(u)... );

}
```

There are also lambdas which are commonly bound with `std::function<T(U)>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, function pointers work exactly the same way in C++ as in C.

Comment: In that case, how could I modify the program above so that it would be valid in C instead of C++?

Comment: It appears to be valid C++ (since it compiles using g++) - I didn't realize that it was valid C also. :)

Comment: I just gave it a quick test to be sure, and it looks fine for either C or C++, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*my_func)(int);

void do_something (my_func f) 
{   
   f (10); 
}

void square (int j) 
{   
   printf ("squared: %d\n", j * j); 
}

void cube (int j) 
{   
    printf ("cubed: %d\n", j * j * j); 
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
   do_something (square);   
   do_something (cube); 
}
```

The output is:

```
squared: 100
cubed: 1000
```

The typedef is to make the syntax for do_something() a bit more readable.

I would like to point out that, since you are using C++ already, it is much easier ways to achieve the same with virtual functions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.

I found a working example program (which can be tested and edited online, and illustrates the concept well): http://ideone.com/6kSTrp#view_edit_box

```
//this was taken from http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html
#include <stdio.h>
void my_int_func(int x)
{
    printf( "%d\n", x );
}


int main()
{
    void (*foo)(int); //pointer to an int function
    foo = &my_int_func;

    /* call my_int_func (note that you do not need to write (*foo)(2) ) */
    foo( 2 );
    /* but if you want to, you may */
    (*foo)( 2 );

    return 0;
}
```