# Passing function as argument does not work

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

I want to pass a function as argument to another function. I searched already Google about information on this and I found already a explanation but it doesn't work for me and I don't know why.

I have following code:

```
void doSomething(uint64_t *);
```

This is my function I want to pass.

```
int functionToCall(int x, int y, void (*f)(uint64_t *));
```

This is my function I want to call and pass the doSomething() function.

In my code now is:

```
uint64_t *state = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t) * 10);
void (*f)(uint64_t *) = doSomething;
functionToCall(2, 3, f(state));
```

If I compile the above code now I get always:

> error: invalid use of void expression

What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error come from the fact that you dont pass a pointer to the function but the function's result (which is void).

If in your function `functionToCall` you want to call `doSomething` with the `state` variable, then you should do something like this:

```
void doSomething(uint64_t *);
int functionToCall(int x, int y, unint64_t * state, void (*f)(uint64_t *))
{
    f(state);

    /* ... */
}

uint64_t *state = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t) * 10);
void (*f)(uint64_t *) = doSomething;
functionToCall(2, 3, state, f);
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you. This was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I did not realize that I have passed the argument for the `doSomething()` function in my `functionToCall` function.

So, the line,

```
functionToCall(2, 3, f(state));
```

Has to be,

```
functionToCall(2, 3, f);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not that good in C but i guess that you could get some help from previous similar post

[How do you pass a function as a parameter in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c)

Hope that my answer helped

Comment: Thank you. I already found this question too. It was helpful but I had  an other mistake.