# Simulate Java's Thread class in C++

Tags: java, c++, multithreading

I am attempting to create my own Thread class in C++ that resembles the Java Thread object. I understand that C++ does not use *implementation* so instead I am keeping a reference to a function as a variable in my C++ Thread Object.

I am having trouble with the second constructor of my Thread Object where you as the user of my thread object are to specify your own function that you want to run.

I am getting a message that says

**Thread.cpp:23:58: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]**

```
#ifndef THREAD_H
#define THREAD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>


class Thread
{
    public:
        Thread();
        Thread(void (*f)(void*));
        ~Thread();

        void* run(void*);
        void start();

    private:
        pthread_t attributes;
        int id;
        void (*runfunction)(void*); //Remember the pointer to the function

};

void* runthread(void* arg); //header


#endif
```

And here is my C++ file

```
#include "Thread.h"

Thread::Thread()
{
    memset(&attributes,0,sizeof(attributes));

}

Thread::Thread(void (*f)(void*))
{
    runfunction = f;
    //(*f)();
}

Thread::~Thread()
{
    id = pthread_create(&attributes, NULL, runthread,this);
}

void Thread::start()
{
    memset(&attributes,0,sizeof(attributes));
    id = pthread_create(&attributes, NULL, *runfunction,this);
}

void* Thread::run(void*)
{

}

void* runthread(void* arg)
{
    Thread* t = (Thread*) arg;
    t->run(NULL);
}
```

Comment: not using C++11 threading capabilities is a deliberate design decision? If not, please take a look at it, because I feel like you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "C++ does not use implementation". Actually it does, just not the keyword. Inheritance in C++ is more flexible than in Java so "implements" happens by design rather than as specific a language feature.

Comment: I think my appreciation for Java and C++11 is higher when I have worked on understanding what was required to make our lives easier for higher level programmers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_create` expects a function with one `void*` parameter returning `void*`, and you provide a function returning `void`.

But, as comments say, use C++ builtin threading is better option.

Comment: Do you have suggestions for my code? I don't understand how to fix it. I am trying to combine functions as arguments with threads. 

As far as not using the built in one, I haven't explored that yet and want to be comfortable how old school threads worked first.

Comment: @Matthew: As this answer and the error message both say: to fix it, change the type of the function pointers (`runfunction`, and the constructor argument `f`) to return `void*` not `void`, since that's what `pthread_create` expects.

Comment: When I do that, I can not longer pass in a function as an argument though. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c

Comment: If you pass a function returning `void*` it should work.

Comment: @Matthew: The function will also have to return `void*`. Just return `NULL` if you don't want to pass any information back to the thread that joins it.

Comment: Awesome! Sorry about that! Thanks! So now the "user" of my Thread object must provide a void* function(void* x)

Looks kind of confusing coming from Java. 

thank you!

Comment: @Matthew: You'll find the C++ threading library less confusing. The `void*` malarkey is because pthreads is a C API, and that's the only sensible way in C to pass generic data in and out of the thread. You could get your class to deal with that (as `std::thread` does), so the user doesn't have to deal with `void*`.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, thanks for the information! My goal in this experiment is design a web document that shows how easy it is to get a chat program (server/client) up in Java using Java's JFrame, ServerSocket, and Thread objects. I then want to show how to do the same thing in generic linux. I am running into the problem that GTK is based in C so if I want to create GUIs, I have to stick to C. I don't know if it is worth it to continue down that road or not.