# Issue passing a function as a parameter in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C and stuck on this. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c) seems widely accepted, but I believe I'm following the correct format and still getting issues.

Here's the offending line in main() (in main.c)

```
PrintWrapper(PrintFunction, *decoded); // *decoded is a char
```

The PrintFunction (also in main.c):

```
void PrintFunction(char c)
{
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

And the prototype declaration (in p1a2.h - in the same directory as main.c)

```
extern void PrintWrapper(void (*)(char), char c);
```

The actual source is hidden away in printwrapper.o (same directory as main.c). This is for an assignment and is a very contrived usage of passing a function as a parameter. I compile the program with

```
g++ main.c printwrapper.o -Wall -g -o tnine
```

and get the compiler error (the backtick is not a typo if that is relevant)

```
<path>/main.c:42: undefined reference to `PrintWrapper(void (*)(char), char'
```

Why does this happen? I'm hoping it's me overlooking something simple.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the prototype as `extern void PrintWrapper(void (*NAMEGOESHERE)(char), char c);` ?

Comment: I have changed it to func. Nothing is differnt

Comment: I also did remember `#include "p1a2.h"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using g++, the compiler expects the function name to be mangled (for more information see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B).
To fix the issue, use `gcc` instead of `g++` or try the following:

```
extern "C" void PrintWrapper(void (*)(char), char*);
```

Comment: This is the best answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed us is valid.

Looks like `printwrapper.o` just don't contain such function.

Comment: This was provided source, so hopefully that is the situation.

Comment: @Matt Then, can you post entire `main.c` here? Or at least short code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: [Repo for reference](https://github.com/Aarskin/P1a). The question is with respect to main2.c

Answer (score 1):

You should use `gcc` instead of `g++` to compile C code. The latter front-end is for C++ code, which symbols are subject to [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Assuming that you are really asking about C language, the proper way to compile your project is:

```
gcc main.c printwrapper.o -Wall -g -o tnine
```

Here is some working sample:

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pla2.h"

void PrintFunction(char c)
{
    printf("%c\n", c);
}

int main(void)
{
    char c = 'a';
    char *decoded = &c;

    PrintWrapper(PrintFunction, *decoded);

    return 0;
}
```

#### pla2.h

```
extern void PrintWrapper(void (*)(char), char c);
```

#### printwrapper.c

```
extern void PrintWrapper(void (*f)(char), char c)
{
    f(c);
}
```

then:

```
$ gcc -c printwrapper.c 

$ gcc main.c printwrapper.o -Wall -g -o tnine

$ ./tnine 
a
```

Comment: Tried it and that introduced about a dozen new compiler errors. g++ is what we are instructed to use.