# Threading Building Blocks parallel_sort?

Tags: c++, tbb

I am reading this page: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506167 and I am trying to understand how exactly I can use my own swap function?

There are no examples about this available and the documentation is not specific enough. Can someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

After Bjarne Stroustrup

```
template<class T>
void swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp {std::move(a)};
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

You pass it like any other. Use just a name.
[How do you pass a function as a parameter in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where do I put this?

Comment: This is really basic syntax. You really need to read tutorial about basic usage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c