# How to implement PHP's array_map() function in C?

Tags: c

I want to implement array_map function using C language.
How can I do this?

```
void * x_array_map(void * func, Array * arr){
   //TODO
}
```

Comment: If you define the Array type elsewhere in C or change "Array" to one of the predefined data types (like char), then you made yourself an empty function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some reference about function as parameter,

[How do you pass a function as a parameter in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define param_type int

// prototype
param_type* array_map (param_type (*f)(param_type), param_type* arr, int n);

// dummy function
int cube(int x) {
    return x*x*x;
}

int main (){
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int* b = array_map(cube, a, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

param_type* array_map (param_type (*f)(param_type), param_type* arr, int n) {
    param_type* result = (param_type*) malloc(n*sizeof(param_type));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        result[i] = f(arr[i]);
    return result;
}
```