# Function call syntax

Tags: c, func

I'm analyzing a C program in which I find a strange fucntion call here is the function definition :

```
static void endSignal (int32_t dummy)
{
  if (nTerminating) return;
  nTerminating=1;
  printf("terminating....\n");
  terminateDLNAsystem();
  sleep(1);
  exit (0);
}
```

This function takes an int32_t parameter !
Now this the main function calling "endSignal"

```
int32_t main (int32_t argc, char **argv)
{
/*Statements
.
.
*/
signal(SIGINT, endSignal);
signal(SIGABRT, endSignal);
signal(SIGQUIT, endSignal);
signal(SIGTERM, endSignal);

return 0;
}
```

the main function call endSignal without any parameter, what happen in this case ?

Comment: It doesn't call `endSignal`, it passes the function as a parameter to another function.

Comment: The `main` prototype is not standard-conforming, BTW;  `main` should return  `int`  and the first argument should be `int`; this in your question is an "other implementation defined manner".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Main function calls `signal` functions and not `endSignal`.

`endSignal` is parameter acting as callback.

This is passing function pointers as arguments.

[How do you pass a function as a parameter in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c)

Comment: This is not the same case.
in my case "signal" is a pre-defined function in <signal.h> so signal can't call the function endSignal to use it ..

Comment: @stojo304 This is exactly the right answer, and of course `signal()` can call its callback function, that's the whole point. Why shouldn't it be able to?

Comment: Yes i just read the definition of signal and understand this point, Thanks

Comment: @unwind , please what is the difference between :
int *i[]= {1,1};
int j[]={2,2};

Comment: first is array of pointers, both points to value 1. In second case, you have 2 integer values, both are set to 1.

Comment: so i[0] is a pointer not an  integer ? because when i print : i[0]=1 !

Comment: Variable itself has a value. "Pointer" exists only for compiler to interpret variables. If you print pointer, it will print as normal variable. If you want to print content on memory where pointer points, use printf("....someModified", *i[0]); Please, don't be agressive.

Comment: @stojo304 Your comments have nothing to do with the question, that's strange. This is not a discussion forum, please post a new question if you think it makes sense to do so.