# Passing non-static member function as argument to a member function in a different class

Tags: c++, function, pointers, syntax

**UPDATE** I realize this question's lacking a proper MCVE, it will take me some time to come up with one. I will update it when I have time to come back to this, sorry. I appreciate the answers thus far.

---

Following [this answer regarding static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413/1757149):

**Declaration** (in `MyClass`)

```
void MyClass::func ( void (MyOtherClass::*f)(int) ); //Use of undeclared identifier 'MyOtherClass'
```

Example of function being passed to func:

```
void MyOtherClass::print ( int x ) {
      printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

**Function call** (in `MyOtherClass`)

```
void MyOtherClass::loop(){
    func(&MyOtherClass::print);
}
```

How can one pass a member function as a parameter of a member function **of another class**?

Comment: Use `std::function` as parameter and a lambda binding to the instance of `MyOtherClass`.

Comment: Are you asking why you are getting a "Use of undeclared identifier" error?

Comment: Unclear what the problem is, but some good, general purpose reading on Method Pointers: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: @DrewDormann Essentially yes! It's a syntax question. I'm trying to pass a member function as a parameter of another member function, but the member functions are in different namespaces, so I can't follow the syntax in various online tutorials/explanations.

Comment: @user4581301 Skimming through that was how I got where I am above. I didn't see any mention of how to deal with passing member functions between classes. Is using `typedef` somehow going to solve that?

Comment: @user4581301 Also meta: sorry that my problem is unclear! Please let me know what you think is vague, I'm not sure how to improve the question without sacrificing brevity as is.

Comment: Unclear because it's hard to tell what you're trying to do with it. You have most of what you are doing correct. Part of this is my fault, I didn't scroll the screen over far enough to see the error message in the comment. Once I did that, it's pretty clear that your problem is `MyOtherClass` has not been declared before `MyClass::func`. The compiler hasn't seen `MyOtherClass` yet and is unsure of how to interpret the unknown identifier. A [mcve] would make everything crystal clear.

Comment: Lacking an MCVE, my top suspicion as to the source of the actual problem is a missing header, probably because of a circular include. More on that here:  [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Answer (score 0):

According to the ISO, the answer is ["don't".](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) Unlike normal functions, a non-static member function is meaningless without an instance of the class. As a workaround, you can have your calling function take a `std::function` and pass it a lambda.

Example:

```
void calling_func(std::function<void()> f);

struct foo
{
    void func();

    void call()
    {
        calling_func([this]{
            func();
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use `std::function` and `std::bind` to that?

```
class MyOtherClass
{
public:
  MyOtherClass() {}
  void print(int x)
  {
    printf("%d\n", x);
  }
};


class MyClass
{
private:
  std::function<void()> CallbackFunc;

public:
  MyClass() {};
  void AssignFunction(std::function<void(int)> callback, int val)
  {
    CallbackFunc = std::bind(callback, val); //bind it again so that callback function gets the integer.
  }

  void DoCallback()
  {
    CallbackFunc(); //we can then just call the callback .this will, call myOtherClass::print(4)
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass myObject;
  MyOtherClass myOtherObject;
  int printval = 4;

  //assign the myObject.callbackfunc with the myOtherClass::print()
  myObject.AssignFunction(std::bind(&MyOtherClass::print, myOtherObject,std::placeholders::_1), 4);

  //calling the doCallback. which calls the assigned function.
  myObject.DoCallback();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: They probably can, and it would be a better solution (though not quite as good a `std::function` and a lambda), but this is not the problem they have run into. The actual problem cannot be nailed down without a MCVE.