# How to make a new function and pass it through another function

Tags: c++, lua

Basically I don't know how to do something like that:

```
    lua_pushcfunction(L, int func(lua_State* L) { 
      printf("hello");
      return 0;
    });
```

I have tried many stuff but doesnt just work

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c

Comment: not what I mean, they create functions then pass them and I want to do it the way there

Comment: Perhaps you need [lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

1. Define the function then push it.

   ```
   int func(lua_State* L) { 
     printf("hello");
     return 0;
   };

   // later...
   lua_pushcfunction(L, func);
   ```

   This is the only way you could do it in C, or before C++11.
2. Use a lambda expression (aka. anonymous function):

   ```
   lua_pushcfunction(L, [](lua_State* L) -> int { 
     printf("hello");
     return 0;
   });
   ```