# How to convert void to typedef void(...)(float)

Tags: c++, qt

I have this on one class:

```
typedef void(*PERCENTAGE_CALLBACK)(float);
```

And I use it on functions like this one:

```
int API_GenerateLayerData(int layerIndex, QByteArray data, int dataSize, PERCENTAGE_CALLBACK callBack);
```

But the thing is that I can't pass a parameter with a void return type and accepts float as a parameter like this:

```
void updateFormattingProcess(float value)
{
    emit ChangeCompose(int(value));
}

void someFunction()
{ 
    //It says cannot convert from 'void' to 'PERCENTAGE_CALLBACK'
    API_GenerateLayerData(1, data, count, updateFormattingProcess(x));
}
```

Comment: This is `updateFormattingProcess(x)` function call, all you need is to pass pointer of this function: `&updateFormattingProcess`.

Comment: how do I set the value of the float in the updateFormattingProcess ?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not using [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: refer to : [How do you pass a function as a parameter in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call the function with `updateFormattingProcess(x)` and pass the result of that function call (which is `void`) as a parameter of type `void(*)(float)`. Instead, just pass a pointer to it:

```
API_GenerateLayerData(1, data, count, &updateFormattingProcess);
//                                    ^ take the addresss of the function
```

Comment: how do I set the value of the float in the updateFormattingProcess ?

Comment: Well, you don't. `API_GenerateLayerData` accepts a function pointer as a parameter. This suggests that it calls `updateFormattingProcess` internally and selects the right parameter?!

Comment: it has another error '&' illegal operation bound member function expression

Comment: So you call `API_GenerateLayerData` from inside a member function, and `updateFormattingsProcess` is a member function, too?

Comment: @TerribleDog - Means your example is not a [mcve]. Please edit your question to **faithfully** represent your issue.

Comment: This is probably because `updateFormattingProcess()` is non-static member of some class. You either need to do it static member or not member of any class.