# Function as template parameter, enforce constraint on return type?

Tags: c++

I have a templated function which accepts a function as a parameter, like

```cpp
template <typename Function>
void apply(Function f) {
    // do something that invokes f(...)
}
```

I want to constrain it so that the return type of `f()` must be some type, say `int`.

I do not want to constrain the parameters of `f` (e.g., assume it takes three `int`s as parameters).

Comment: If you know `f`'s signature, you can solve it by typing out its type instead of using a template, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413/5825294).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Not really; that prevents functors, lambdas, ....

Comment: OP what have you tried so far

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis In this case, I don't know the argument types, only the return type.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I haven't tried anything other than trying fruitlessly to figure out how to phrase this to Google.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a naive solution, that combines `std::enable_if_t`, `std::is_same_v`, `decltype` and `std::declval`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <
    typename Function,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<
            decltype(std::declval<Function>()(
                std::declval<int>(),
                std::declval<int>(),
                std::declval<int>()
            )),
            int
        >
    >
>
void apply(Function f) {
    f(1,2,3);
}

int foo(int x, int y, int z);
char bar(int x, int y, int z);

int main()
{
    apply(foo);
    apply(bar);
}
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bbebd553dd052d8))

`foo` works but `bar` doesn't.

This should also behave as expected for alternative overloads of `foo`, because part of the machinery is specifying the types of the arguments we're going to provide to the `Function`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to adapt it if I don't want to also constrain the arity / argument types of `f`?

Comment: @rgov I don't think that's meaningful. Different overloads can have different return types. You _have_ to specify which parameter list you're going to supply before you can do any comparison.

Comment: @rgov Why do you think you need to do this? It's a bit weird.

Comment: In reality it's more like I'm doing `std::invoke(f, args)` where `args` is an array whose size varies depending on the rank of an array type (which is another template parameter I omitted from the example).

Comment: Please ask your actual question not some other question so that we don't waste our time...

Comment: Sorry that you felt it was a waste of time. Of course, every question is a distillation of a more complex scenario, where the questioner tries to highlight the salient bits. Otherwise it will just be "please fix my code" with a 9,000 line dump. I believe I described the question accurately.

Comment: This answer answers the question as it was at that time. And it shows interesting TMP stuff!

Comment: @rgov What seems to have happened is that you distilled your question more than you intended, but (assuming good faith) did not realize that until the question was answered. A polite thing to do at that point would be to thank the answerer for the effort by accepting the answer, then post a new question with the additional constraints.

Comment: @rgov After thinking about it, this answer possibly answers your real question as well. You might just need to bring back that other template parameter you omitted from the example and use it within `enable_if_t`. Just a matter of un-distilling, if I understand the situation well enough.