# Functions as function argument

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

I hope my formatting etc. is ok as this is the first time I post a question. Anyways, I'm searching and couldn't find an explanation why the two different function definitions/declarations are equivalent to each other:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int quadrat( int x )
{
    return x*x;
}

void printTable_1( int start, int end, int step, int (*func)( int x ) )
{
    for ( int i = start; i <= end; i+=step )
    {
        cout << i << "\t" << func(i) << '\n';
    }
}

void printTable_2( int start, int end, int step, int func( int x ) )
{
    for ( int i = start; i <= end; i+=step )
    {
        cout << i << "\t" << func(i) << '\n';
    }
}
    
int main()
{
    printTable_1(1,10,1,quadrat);
    printTable_2(1,10,1,quadrat);

    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is that I didn't explicitely defined in the function "printTable_2" a function pointer like in the function "printTable_1" and it still expects one. Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: `int func(int)` as an argument is very much similar to declaring an "array" argument (e.g. `int a[]`) in that the compiler treats it as a pointer.

Comment: if you look at the assembly code you will see that both are translate to function ptr [godbold](https://godbolt.org/z/4n3dfW)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413/13071379 may be this answere could ease out things for you

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: @UmarFarooq it doesn't seem like the answer in your link is quite relevant, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53503192/7426641) answer to the same question does.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, that's what I was also thinking. However, I wanted to find proof of it in the standard which I found in the link posted by Benny K.

Comment: @yaodav, nice website! Very cool to quickly look at the assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

Both definitions are the same to the compiler. A rough overview about this behavior can be found in the book [Effective STL](http://www.uml.org.cn/c%2B%2B/pdf/EffectiveSTL.pdf) starting at Page 20 or PDF Page 26.

> Let's now look at three more function declarations. The first one
> declares a function g taking a parameter that's a pointer to a
> function taking nothing and returning a double:
>
> ```cpp
> int g(double (*pf)());
> ```
>
> Here's another way to say the same thing. The only difference is that
> pf is declared using non-pointer syntax (a syntax that's valid in both
> C and C++):
>
> ```cpp
> int g(double pf()); // same as above; pf is> implicitly a pointer
> ```
>
> As usual, parameter names may be omitted, so
> here's a third declaration for g, one where the name pf has been
> eliminated:
>
> ```cpp
> int g(double ()); // same as above; parameter name is omitted
> ```

So in your example we have

```cpp
int (*func)( int x )
```

and

```cpp
int func( int x )
```

As you can see it is the same way as in the example, where we can just omit the parentheses around `func` and the `*`. It is still exactly the same to the compiler in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Through testing it, I as already aware that both variants work. Then I started searching for validation to find a statement about it in the standards but couldn't find anything why I posted the question.