Using S_ISREG() (and other macros) as parameter to function
I am trying to create a function that will be generally used to determine if a file/directory exists, if it is within a certain path, and if it is of the specified type (S_ISREG, S_ISDIR, ...
Here are the parts of the source pertaining to this question:
int checkExists(const char *name, void *func(int))) {
   struct stat st ;
   int returnValue = DOES_NOT_EXIST ;
   BOOL isInSourceHierarchy, isInTargetHierarchy ;

   if (stat(name, &st) != -1) {
      returnValue = EXISTS ;
      if (memcmp(name, top_dir, strlen(top_dir)))
         returnValue |= IN_SOURCE_STRUCTURE ;
      if (memcmp(name, tgt_dir, strlen(tgt_dir)))
         returnValue |= IN_TARGET_STRUCTURE ;
      if (func != NULL) {
         if (objType == func(st.st_mode))
            returnValue |= RIGHT_TYPE ;
      }
   }

   return returnValue ;
}

. . . 

if (S_ISREG(0)) {} // Yes, I know, I know.  This is for demonstration only.
if (checkExists(old, S_ISREG)) {
   // Do something
 } else { // Old file doesn't exist
   // Do something else
 }

When trying to compile this, I get:
linkStructure.c:642:31: error: ‘S_ISREG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  642 |          if (checkExists(old, S_ISREG)) {
      |                               ^~~~~~~

As can be seen, there is no complaint about the macro used as designed, of course.  So my question is: Is there a way for me to reference the macro in my source like this?  Or will I be left to basically emulate the macro in my function?  (I suppose I could pass the expected type rather than the function, but for the sake of clarity, I would like to understand this limitation.)

Note that you return DOES_NOT_EXIST if stat fails, but stat can fail for other reasons. Another common reason is lack of permission.

It says S_ISREG is undefined because the preprocessor doesn't ignore the parenthesis. #define FOO() defines FOO(), not FOO.
Also, your function expects a function pointer as parameter, but macros are compile-time only symbols, you can't take its address.
But you can just wrap it in a function instead:
int isReg(int mode)
{
    return S_ISREG(mode);
}

Now you can use it as you wanted:
checkExists(old, isReg);

And you keep the flexibility of your original code.

Perfect solution though I disagree about the parentheses.  If I want to pass the function print(), for example, I reference it as print, not as print() (see accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c)  But that's picking nits.  Love this solution.

Macros and functions are completely different things handled by different programs. The preprocessor is a "stupid" copy and paste machine that does exactly that and has no knowledge of functions. print is a function compiled to actual code with an address. The operator () executes its code, and its name holds its address as value.

No, you can't do what you are trying to achieve without extra steps.
S_ISREG doesn't exist, and there's no telling into what S_ISREG(x) expands.

Remember that macros simply perform token substitution, which means that S_ISREG(x) gets replaced with different code before parsing even begins (in theory). Say it expands to something like ((x) & S_IFREG). How can you pass that to the your function? You'd have to create a function from it.
typedef int ModeCheck( int );

int s_isreg( int mode ) {
   return S_ISREG( mode );
}

int check_exists( const char *qfn, ModeCheck *mode_check ) {
   ...

   if ( mode_check( st.st_mode ) ) { 
      ...
   }

   ...
}

check_exists( qfn, s_isreg );


Alternatively, you could pass S_IFREG (which expands to a mask) and do the appropriate bit operation yourself.
int check_exists( const char *qfn, int mode_mask ) {
   ...

   if ( ( st.st_mode & S_IFMT ) == mode_mask ) ) ) { 
      ...
   }

   ...
}

check_exists( qfn, S_IFREG );

However, you have less flexibility with this second approach. With the first approach, you could use more complex checks.
int s_isreg_or_dir( int mode ) {
   return S_ISREG( mode ) || S_ISDIR( mode );
}

But you can't do so with the second approach.

Thanks for the answer.  It's the "why" part that I'm looking for.  I understand what you mean (doesn't exist except as a macro), but technically if it didn't exist, then the line before would (also) give a not-defined error.

Re "I understand what you mean (doesn't exist except as a macro)", That's not what I said, and it's not true. S_ISREG doesn't exist at all. Only S_ISREG(x) exists. Those are different.

Re "It's the "why" part that I'm looking for", I did explain that, but I have expanded my explanation.

The S_ISREG macro is a function-like macro, so simply using it as S_ISREG is invalid.
You'll need to instead pass in the flag for the mode in question, i.e. S_IFREG, an perform a bitmask with that and the file mode.
int checkExists(const char *name, int ftype) {
   struct stat st ;
   int returnValue = DOES_NOT_EXIST ;
   BOOL isInSourceHierarchy, isInTargetHierarchy ;

   if (stat(name, &st) != -1) {
      returnValue = EXISTS ;
      if (memcmp(name, top_dir, strlen(top_dir)))
         returnValue |= IN_SOURCE_STRUCTURE ;
      if (memcmp(name, tgt_dir, strlen(tgt_dir)))
         returnValue |= IN_TARGET_STRUCTURE ;
     if ((st.st_mode & S_IFMT) == ftype)
        returnValue |= RIGHT_TYPE ;
   }

   return returnValue ;
}

. . . 

if (checkExists(old, S_IFREG)) {
   // Do something
 } else { // Old file doesn't exist
   // Do something else
 }

